# AutoComplete Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery for AutoComplete. I'm using onFocus() to start the autocomplete.

I am having problems showing the animation for the AutoComplete:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

function getAutoCompleteDesignations(){

    var availableTags = new Array();
    availableTags = {!JSONDesignationString};



    $('[id$=tags]').autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });

}
```

How can I get the animation to show upon typing in the input box?

Comment: Why don't you use `j$.autocomplete()`?

Comment: At the beginning of this snippet you declared `j$` as no conflict, which copies the jQuery object to that variable. Assuming there's a reason why you did that I would use that variable instead of `$`.

Comment: very clear, thanks. I'm a lil' apprehensive whenit comes to javascript. can you show an example?, sorry.

Comment: No problem. Glad to have helped